# Tensorflow is slow on windows with anaconda and GTX1660super

Tags: windows, tensorflow, anaconda, conv-neural-network, nvidia

I have a neural network code that works with 13749 training images and 3429 validation images. The network model is quite simple and takes more than 1 hour for each epoch, while it should take about 90 seconds.

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(
        Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3), name="conv1")
    )
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="maxpool1"))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", name="conv2"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="maxpool2"))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", name="conv3"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="maxpool3"))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(30, activation="relu", name="dense"))
    model.add(Dense(len(len(animals), activation="sigmoid", name="final"))

    model.compile(
        loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=["accuracy"]]
    )
    model.summary()
```

I have tried several versions of tensorflow-gpu, cudnn and cuda and I get tensorflow to detect the GPU, but the training is very slow. In other computers the training takes less than 2 minutes per epoch.

Comment: Have you checked if the calculation actually runs on the GPU?

Comment: I don't know, but when the code is running, the GPU shows that it is using more than 5GB of the total 6GB that the GPU has.